# Bug report whilte upgrading from 12.04, is this a real problem?

Tags: upgrade

Could not install `/var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm2_2.4.39-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

The upgrade will continue but the `/var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm2_2.4.39-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` package may not be in a working state. Please consider submitting a bug report about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is a real problem. The bug report is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdrm/+bug/1068165), as is the fix, which is to remove the offending file, then try again. You can remove the offending file with `$ sudo rm /usr/share/doc/libdrm2/changelog.Debian.gz`